# How to configure Symfony 4 with a custom SQLite driver?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've been migrating an old Symfony 3 application to Symfony 4.3. 
In the old one there is a custom SQLite driver which extends the Doctrine one and provides a "like" function.

According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) I should still be able to do:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver:       pdo_sqlite
    url:          "%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%"
    driver_class: App\DBAL\MyDatabaseDriver
```

However, the driver is most definitely not being called at all. I've attached a debugger and the `App\DBAL\MyDatabaseDriver` class is not being called. Instead, the `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver` one is being called.

I have tried removing the `driver:` and leaving only `driver_class` but with no effect.

Anybody have ideas? I've been stuck at this for more time than I would like to admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've missed an important part of the documentation:

```
# if the url option is specified, it will override the above config
url: mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
```

In other words, the right way to do this is:

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///:memory:?driverClass=App\DBAL\MyDatabaseDriver
```

and remove the `driver_class` from the configuration.